# Legacy Password Hasher Not Working Migrating CodeIgniter2 to Cake 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have a legacy CRM application that I am migrating from Code Igniter 2.x to Cake 3. I am attempting to implement a Legacy Password Hasher and then move everything to the Cake 3 password hasher.

I have been unable to get authentication to work. As you'll see I've had to deviate from various cake defaults, in particular all tables were created as singular names. Not sure if that's causing any issues. It's been an ordeal. If it matters, Admin exists as a plugin.

**AppController**

```
namespace Admin\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController as BaseController;

class AppController extends BaseController
{
    public function initialize() {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
            'loginAction' => '/admin/login', // routes to /admin/user/login
            'authenticate' => [
                'Form' => [
                    'passwordHasher' => [
                        'className' => 'Legacy',
                    ],
                    'fields' => [
                        'username' => ['email_address','handle'], 
                        'password' => 'password',
                    ],
                    'userModel' => 'User',
                ],
            ],
            'storage' => 'Session'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**UserController**

```
if( $this->request->is('post') ){

    $this->loadModel('User');
    $me = $this->User->find()->where([
                'type IN ' => ['superuser','administrator','user','publisher'],
                'status IN ' => ['active','suspended'],
                'OR' => [
                    'email_address' => $this->request->data('username'), 'handle' => $this->request->data('username')
                ]
            ])->first();

    if( $me->status == 'active' ){

        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if( $user ){
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            if( $this->Auth->authenticationProvider()->needsPasswordRehash() ){
                $user = $this->User->get($this->Auth->user('id'));
                $user->password = $this->request->data('password');
                $this->User->save($user);
            }
            switch($user->type){
                case 'superuser':
                    $url = '/admin/dashboard/super';
                    break;
                case 'admin':
                    $url = '/admin/dashboard/';
                    break;
                case 'publisher':
                    $url = '/admin/dashboard/publisher';
                    break;
                case 'property':
                    $url = '/admin/dashboard/property';
                    break;
            }

            return $this->redirect($url);
        }
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect'), [
        'key' => 'auth'
    ]);
}
```

**LegacyPasswordHasher**

```
namespace App\Auth;

use Cake\Auth\AbstractPasswordHasher;

class LegacyPasswordHasher extends AbstractPasswordHasher
{

    public function hash($password){
        $salt_length = 16;
        $salt = substr($password, 0, $salt_length);

        return $salt . sha1($salt . $password);
    }

    public function check($password, $hashedPassword){
        return $this->hash($password) === $hashedPassword;
    }
}
```

The legacy password hasher does not even seem to be called. I did a work around to force authentication by doing my own check and then setting the auth user data. Still after that when rehashing the password using Cakes DefaultPasswordHasher authentication failed.

Comment: I don't think that the default form and base authenticator support compound fields (multiple values, multiple columns) or multi-column checks (single value, multiple columns). Which one are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The legacy system (developed by someone else) allowed for login by username or email. Even when switching to 'username' => 'email_address' only it still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There were a few issues here. One, I needed to change the configuration to this:

```
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'loginAction' => '/admin/login',
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'finder' => 'auth',
                'passwordHasher' => [
                    'className' => 'Legacy',
                ],
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email_address', 
                    'password' => 'password',
                ],
                'userModel' => 'User',
            ],
        ],
        'storage' => 'Session'
    ]);
```

Next, the field I posted needed to be email_address and not username. Last, there was a bug in my implementation of Code Igniters password hasher. It ended up needing to look like this:

```
public function hash($password){
    $salt_length = 16;
    $salt = substr($this->salt, 0, $salt_length);

    return $salt . sha1($salt . $password);
}

public function check($password, $hashedPassword){
    $this->salt = $hashedPassword;
    return $this->hash($password) === $hashedPassword;
}
```

I also needed a custom finder query added to UserTable:

```
public function findAuth(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    $query
        ->select(['id', 'email_address','handle','password'])
        ->where(['User.status' => 'active']);

    return $query;
}
```

To handle users being able to login with a username or email_address I will just override the the posted value if its not an email address by looking up the user by handle prior to auth doing its thing.

I hope this helps someone.